# Wriring pyarrow metadata for a partitioned dataset

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow

The `pyarrow` documentation contains an example of how to write a dataset with `metadata`.

However a slight modification to the example results in an error. In the code below I've added a partition column (n_legs). The parquet files are correctly produced by the metadata fails with

```
RuntimeError: AppendRowGroups requires equal schemas.
This schema has 2 columns, other has 1
```

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

table = pa.table({'n_legs': [2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 100],
                  'animal': ["Flamingo", "Parrot", "Dog", "Horse",
                             "Brittle stars", "Centipede"]})

metadata_collector = []
root_path = Path("animals.parquet")
pq.write_to_dataset(
    table,
    root_path,
    partition_cols=["n_legs"],
    metadata_collector=metadata_collector,
)

#Write the ``_common_metadata`` parquet file without row groups statistics
pq.write_metadata(table.schema, root_path / "_common_metadata")


#Write the ``_metadata`` parquet file with row groups statistics of all files
pq.write_metadata(
    table.schema, root_path / "_metadata", metadata_collector=metadata_collector
)
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error occurs because, once you partition, the written parquet files no longer have the partitioned column. In your example, the parquet files would only have the "animal" column (the n_legs column is part of the path, `/n_legs=2/something.parquet`). The schema of the table (i.e. `table.schema`) would still have 2 columns, hence the error.

To circumvent this, you could do something like the following:

```
non_partitioned_cols = [s for s in table.schema if x not in {'n_legs'}]
partial_schema = table.schema.empty_table().select(non_partitioned_cols).schema
pq.write_metadata(
    partial_schema, root_path / "_metadata", metadata_collector=metadata_collector
)
```

Comment: I'm sure you're correct, but if the schema is being written to the root folder (which contains multiple folders each of which contain a partition) it seems to me that the schema 'should` contain the partition columns even though the parquet files don't. Otherwise you lose the information regarding the type of the `n_legs` column. And it gets treated a `string` rather than `int` when you read the dataset back. My workaround is to manually construct the full schema including the partition column then read the dataset using the manual schema and that works,